# Programatically create angled line background in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have been looking for some type of tutorial or suggestion on how to create light grey angled lines to fill a UIView that I can use as a background to another UIView.

This is an example of the type of look I am aiming for.

[image]

I am just not sure where to start.

Comment: I also understand I could probably use an image to achive this.. however I want to code it (if possible) as the UIView can change size dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use CoreImage. There's actually a filter made just for that purpose.

This code produces a `UIImage` with the exact pattern that you're aiming for. You can just put it on a `UIImageView`:

```
CIFilter* stripesFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIStripesGenerator"];
[stripesFilter setValue: [CIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0] forKey:@"inputColor0"];
[stripesFilter setValue: [CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forKey:@"inputColor1"];
[stripesFilter setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0] forKey:@"inputWidth"];

NSValue *rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-45.0f / 180.0f * M_PI)];
CIFilter *transformFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, stripesFilter.outputImage, @"inputTransform", rotation, nil];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @NO}];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:transformFilter.outputImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
UIImage *angledStripesImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

To use this code you'll also need to link CoreImage.framework with your target.

Comment: One question are there any frameworks i should be importing to get this to work as I have several errors when I try to compile.. im investigating now.. but thought you may know.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Yes, you need to link the CoreImage framework with your target. I've updated the answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Programmatically create a UIBezierPath that follows that pattern.
2. Create a CAShapeLayer and configure the color and thickness.
3. Set the CAShapeLayer's `path` parameter to the UIBezierPath (specifically the path's `CGPath` parameter).
4. Add the CAShapeLayer as a sublayer of the view's backing layer.

Comment: AWesome.. thanks Im going to give this ago...